Loading custom map with map_server
I'm trying to create a launch file that will include the nav2_bringup package's localization_launch.py file with a custom map.
    # Get map yaml file path
    map_yaml_file = LaunchConfiguration('map')
    map_yaml_file_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
        'map',
        default_value=os.path.join(
            get_package_share_directory('my_package_with_map'), 'maps', 'my_custom_map.yaml'),
        description='Full path to the map yaml file to load')

    # Run localization module
    localization_cmd = IncludeLaunchDescription(
    PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
        os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('nav2_bringup'), 'launch/localization_launch.py')),
    launch_arguments={'map': map_yaml_file}.items())


    ld = LaunchDescription()
    ld.add_action(map_yaml_file_cmd)
    ld.add_action(localization_cmd)

When I run the launch file, I get the following messages from map_server:
[map_server-6] [INFO] [1733429440.155744849] [map_server]: Configuring
[map_server-6] [ERROR] [1733429440.157427257] [map_server]: Caught exception in callback for transition 10
[map_server-6] [ERROR] [1733429440.157463695] [map_server]: Original error: parameter 'yaml_filename' is not initialized
[map_server-6] [WARN] [1733429440.157506975] [map_server]: Error occurred while doing error handling.
[map_server-6] [FATAL] [1733429440.157527638] [map_server]: Lifecycle node map_server does not have error state implemented

What am I missing here? It looks like the localization_launch.py file should be substituting yaml_filename with map on this line (line 55 on my version):
    # Create our own temporary YAML files that include substitutions
    param_substitutions = {
        'use_sim_time': use_sim_time,
        'yaml_filename': map_yaml_file}

I've also tried setting the map yaml filename on command line with ros2 launch my_package_with_launch my_launch.py map:=/full/path/to/map.yaml but I get the same messages. As of now, I am only trying to load the map using default parameters so I did not specify a nav parameter file. It looks like the localization_launch.py should be loading the default nav2 parameter file if no other is specified.

Did you add you map folder to install command in your CMakeLists.txt file? Like install( DIRECTORY launch maps DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME}/ )

It was related to this issue: https://github.com/ros-navigation/navigation2/issues/3644
It works fine when I change the parameters argument in the ComposableNode constructor call in the nav2_bringup's localization_launch.py file to what is below.
            parameters=[configured_params,
                        {'yaml_filename': map_yaml_file}], # Added this to parameters

